# Spring injection with Java's Optional

Tags: java, spring, option-type

When trying to inject an `Optional<T>`, Spring never calls my bean, and instead injects an `Optional.empty()`.

Here is some sample code:

```
@Configuration
public class Initialize {

    @Value("optionalValue")
    private String testString;

    @Bean (name = "getOptionalString")
    public Optional<String> getOptionalString() {
        return Optional.of(this.testString); //breakpoint put here, is never called
    }
}

@Component
public class Test {

    public Test(@Qualifier("getOptionalString") Optional<String> optional) {
      // optional's value is Optional.empty() here
    }
```

I noticed that (by putting a breakpoint) the `@Bean` is never called. If I were to remove the `Optional<String>`, and simply return a `String`, then it works!

I know `Spring` has its own optional dependency but I am perplexed as to why this doesn't work (whatever I read online says it should), and I also don't understand how it initialized it to `Optional.empty()`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[The documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation) says:

> you can express the non-required nature of a particular dependency through Java 8’s java.util.Optional, as the following example shows:
>
> ```
> public class SimpleMovieLister {
>
>     @Autowired
>     public void setMovieFinder(Optional<MovieFinder> movieFinder) {
>         ...
>     }
> }
> ```

So using Optional as the type of a bean is not a good idea.

Comment: I cannot see why Optional is not a good idea as well as why Spring does not inject implementation in the question above(

Comment: @Dedyshka You don't need the Optional declaration in the Bean method, you'll only need Optional where it is autowired.